# Does dividing by a number take the same time as multiplying by the decimal

Tags: time

I've heard that division takes longer than multiplication, so do these two take the same amount of time or is one faster?

```
x = 10 * 0.5f

x = 10 / 2f
```

Comment: This is a premature optimization question. Do you have code where it appears that this sort of operation is a bottleneck or affecting performance as shown by a profiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in most languages multiplying by 0.5f is faster

source: [source](https://hatebin.com/yyyiwokcqy)